# Haskell - Read Lines from Handle without blocking

Tags: haskell, concurrency, io

I want to process the stdout of a process launched via `createProcess` linewise, but I can't  wait until a new line is available. My application will do something like this:

1. Get all full lines from the output of some external program that are available without waiting
2. Launch a job that processes these lines
3. Once the job is completed, wait until at least one line of the external program's output is available and repeat

I don't know how to implement 1. Is there an equivalent to `Handle`'s `hGetBufNonBlocking` that operates on a per-line basis? If not, what is the Haskell™ way to solve this problem? Use `hReady` and `hGetChar` to implement custom line buffering or some form of concurrency?

Comment: `but I can't wait until a new line is available` Do you mean that you want to process the line as it is being generated, perhaps without wholly keeping it in memory?

Comment: No, I do want to process only full lines. I edited the post for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of tinkering I came up with this, hope it helps you:

```hs
dealWithLine :: String -> IO ()
dealWithLine l = putStrLn $ l ++ "; length: " ++ (show $ length l)

main = getContents >>= (\s -> mapM dealWithLine $ lines s)
```

The key function for you is `getContents` which takes input as is, is none blocking and you can feed it to whatever function you want in order to deal with stdin.